# What is this type of road called in English?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I’m looking for a word or a phrase for describing this kind of [road](https://www.google.ro/search?q=transfagarasan&biw=1024&bih=677&tbm=isch&imgil=7VPsqo6TlqYYzM%253A%253BHP5XPo9hOaj8CM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fen.wikipedia.org%25252Fwiki%25252FTransf%25252525C4%2525252583g%25252525C4%2525252583r%25252525C4%2525252583%25252525C8%2525252599an&source=iu&pf=m&fir=7VPsqo6TlqYYzM%253A%252CHP5XPo9hOaj8CM%252C_&usg=__14jl1-KY9yvyNrt02DgdVJOLK6Y%3D&ved=0CDsQyjc&ei=XXSzVIG2D8W1Ucz1gNAB#imgdii=_&imgrc=GbDXw7aN9yWO2M%253A%3B-BgAS6d7JBB6OM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fupload.wikimedia.org%252Fwikipedia%252Fcommons%252F7%252F74%252FRomania-roads-DN7C.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fro.wikipedia.org%252Fwiki%252FTransf%2525C4%252583g%2525C4%252583r%2525C4%252583%2525C8%252599an%3B646%3B454) which usually is constructed in the mountain areas, but not only:

[image]
<sup>image a representative sample from Google images, query = transfagarasan</sup>

In my language we call this *serpentine* a word used as a noun (not adjective) to describe its shape.

If I wanted to write an article about this road, a road constructed in the mountains provided with many turns and angles like in the above link, which word would be more appropriate to use?

Comment: Incidentally, in Russian it is also "*[serpantin](https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD_(%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0)&oldid=66997390)*", but the Wikipedia article has no interwiki links.

Comment: Road names differ quite a bit between English speaking countries - do you have a particular audience in mind?

Comment: @Dan, I would like to know it in general, not for a particular area or country.

Comment: @LucianSava That's kind of the problem. The top rated answer doesn't really work in England - I've never heard anyone refer to "serpentine" or "switchback", although people could probably work it out.

Comment: @Dan, thank you for your input. Then the issue is way broader than I thought.

Comment: Well, you could use a metaphor, like *the road twisted itself (uphill) like a...*

Comment: The road double backed upon itself 44 times as it zigzaged up the mountain. Or use switchback, and let readers look the word up. At least you are using it correctly. Or serpentine.

Comment: @Dan Is there a name that is commonly used for this type of road in BrE?  Switchback is very common in AmE for hiking trails and roads that wind back and forth on themselves to make ascent/descent easier.  I can find *switchback* used on a number of hiking sites in the UK, but not for roads.

Comment: The road in the picture is described with these words on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transf%C4%83g%C4%83r%C4%83%C8%99an): "The most spectacular route is from the North to South. It is a **winding** road, dotted with steep hairpin turns, long S-curves, and sharp descents." [Winding road](https://www.google.fr/search?q=winding+road&complete=0&hl=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X) search on Google images.

Comment: 'Snaking' up (or down) the hill.

Comment: @mins - Funny, though, how the images for _winding road_ have much gentler curves that the images for _[serpentine road](https://www.google.fr/search?q=serpentine+road&complete=0&hl=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X)_. As your Wikipedia quote suggests, the term _winding road_ doesn't say enough in and of itself.

Comment: @J.R. Agreed Jason! In French we have something very specific for a road with hairpin turns: 'une route en lacets' (literally: 'a road made of hairpin turns'), [Google search](https://www.google.fr/search?q=route+en+lacets&complete=0&site=webhp&tbm=isch). This expression translates well into 'winding road', according to [Google translate](https://translate.google.fr/?hl=fr&tab=iT#fr/en/route%20en%20lacets) (not my reference, though!).

Comment: It's always in mountainous areas, you only need this type of road when the elevation changes quickly. Just call it a pass as they do here when describing the "sawtooth oscillation of metronomic vacillation, between hairpin bends that bitch-slap it from zig to zag and back to zig" http://www.caranddriver.com/features/a-monster-lamborghini-meets-italys-monster-road-feature

Comment: @geoO, it's really amazing your link. Certainly it is needed when elevation changes but as I specified in my question: "not only". +1 for your comment.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*Preface ADDED 14 Jan/Jan 14, 00:11 GMT/UTC: This answer, as the OP Lucian Sava is well aware, has been written from an AmE perspective. Actually, it is written from the perspective of the variety of AmE that I speak. I think Lucian gets by now that English usage is not universal, as I had already indicted in my anwer. Let the conversation continue, by all means!*

---

Serpentine is fine, but in English I am pretty sure we would use it as an *adjective* describing the road. Such a road is also called, in familiar terms, a curvy mountain road. More technically, it is any road that contains many [switchbacks or hairpin curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpin_turn)

[Switchback](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/switch-back) can refer to entirety of such a road. But this may not reflect universal usage.

I think serpentine (adjective) would be the more universally recognized word.

You can do an image search for both "switchback road" and "serpentine road" and get many of the same images.

Thus saith the snake:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Hairpin, I knew it from formula 1 but I didn’t make the connection.+1

Comment: "Switchback" specifically connotes a mountain road by analogy to hiking trails, whereas (at least to me, a native speaker from the northeast USA) "serpentine" connotes "twisting" more generally -- that is, "serpent-like" or "snake-like"

Comment: We bowled along a road that curved its spine / Superbly sinuous and **[serpentine](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Notes_on_the_Firth)** ..

Comment: @CopperKettle poetic, but not colloquial

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: `serpens` is latin and means `snake`.

Comment: @ssdecontrol, I see nothing wrong with calling the roads in the OP "switchbacks", and in fact it was the first thing that came to mind when I saw the images.

Comment: @BrianS that's what I meant to imply: "switchback" makes a lot more sense than "serpentine" here, to me. But apparently my experience isn't representative

Comment: "Serpentine is fine". Well, not in British English - if that is a requirement. "Switchback" is also very (North?) American. In British English we would simply describe this as a "winding road". And you could perhaps qualify this with "... with hairpin bends".

Comment: @w3d Welcome to the conversation. Your perspective is most welcome to what has become a highly voluble set of threads. I believe by now that the OP Lucian Sava is well aware that I wrote my answer from an AmE perspective and that words such as switchback, serpentine (which at least one of your countryman--David Richerby--as well as just about every BrE dictionary I consulted) says is fine *in British English*. I already indicated that switchback is not universal. And I'm getting that you English do not have curves but (the?) bends. :)

Comment: I can't quite upvote this answer, because 'serpentine' is a general adjective that means something (anything) is twisty. A switchback is a road that goes up a mountain using hairpin turns to ease the elevation change. It's a general adjective that could apply to this type of road, versus a specific noun that means exactly this type of road.

Comment: @DCShannon And thus by your comment, we can guess that you speak American English! :) Welcome to the club! :) Of course the OP did not ask for a specific noun but for a word *or* phrase. The ironic thing is that I rarely use the word, switchback; I just say curvy mountain road. Or curvy-wurvy. :)

Comment: @CarSmack Yes, lots of bends, bendy roads and bends to go round, but not necessarily round the bend! :)

Comment: @w3d I sure do love the traffic circles. That is one thing that I wish the USA had a **lot** more of. We have three in the entire country (well, maybe four).

Comment: @CarSmack - you should move to Carmel, IN - their mayor went to Europe a decade ago or something and fell in love with them.

Answer (score 13):

Suitable words might be:

*winding* or *twisting*

You could check the [Thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/winding?s=t) for more options.

These are very general adjectives and don't just apply to mountain passes (a *pass* is a road that crosses a mountain, but it does not have to be winding). Note that there is a pass over the Pennines called *Snake Pass*, but that is its name.

You could use *Serpentine* but that is rather poetic sounding.

The type of turn that loops back on itself is known as a *hairpin turn*.

Comment: Hi. Welcome. I thought of *winding* but an image search for "winding road" returns quite different images than a search for "switchback road" or "serpentine road."

Comment: I thought of _switchback_ but when I Googled it and looked at the associated articles, there was a suggestion that it applied to a road that went up-and-down rather than one that had lots of curves. I would suggest checking the other adjectives in the Thesaurus. For example _tortuous_ is often used if you want to emphasise the danger. You can combine the words for extra effect: _tortuously winding_. However, I don't think you will find a word that is especially made for the purpose.

Comment: Switchback, by definition of multiple dictionaries, means a (mountain road) having plenty of hairpin turns.

Comment: 'Switchback' feels to me particularly Am E rather than Br E. I, of course, know what it means, but it feels like an adopted rather than 'native' word in Br E. Edit - that doesn't mean I would in any way object to it… especially as I can't think of anything better ;)

Comment: @CarSmack Although a search for `winding road` does return the same/similar images as in the question.

Answer (score 11):

In the U.S., we call those mountainous roads "switchback" roads, with the individual turns called "hairpin" turns.

https://www.google.com/search?q=switchback+road&espv=2&biw=1147&bih=685&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=qUy0VKO3KtWxogSMpYDIBw&ved=0CB0QsAQ&dpr=0.9

Answer (score 6):

I often refer such paths/roads as ..

> *zig zag* roads or paths

Searching this on [Google Images](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=zigzag%20roads&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=e4izVNqbBMa3uQTk2oG4AQ&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=923) supports this word.

In my state, we have such place called [Saputara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saputara). It's famous for its hairpin curves or zigzag roads. Most of the tourists experience [motion sickness](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/motionsickness.html) due to this.

Comment: Wonderful images. +1

Comment: -1 for mentioning motion sickness. I am just **kidding**! But, yeah, such roads can definitely bring that on, as well as vertigo if high up.

Comment: @CarSmack Aw...true! but cannot bring 'medical' out of me! In my case, typing of such words is dyskinesia. haha!

Comment: I don't think zig-zag implies anything about mountains or elevation changes.

Comment: @DCShannon But surely a zigzag road refers to its *shape*, as does serpentine. Serpentine doesn't imply anything about mountains or elevation changes either. :) But roads with such a shape are found at elevation changes, including those due to mountains.

Comment: A nice example of a 'zig zag' road in the UK is [Zig Zag Road](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Zig+Zag+Rd,+Surrey/@51.2526097,-0.3115565,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x4875e6cf7a824951:0x31566aeb71a3609), which goes up the side of Box Hill in Surrey, and was part of the cycling route for the 2012 Olympics.

Comment: @CarSmack I agree serpentine doesn't imply anything about mountains or elevation changes, that's why I think it is also a poor answer. I understand that switchback is not in common usage all over the world, but if nobody else has a specific word for this specific thing, then that's the word.

Answer (score 4):

I think *serpentine road* or *winding road* is as close as you're likely to get.  Personally, I prefer *serpentine road*.  To my knowledge there isn't a single-word noun form of this phrase that is generally understood.

Another user mentioned *switchback*, but that strikes me as less likely to be widely understood.

Comment: "Another user mentioned switchback" - TBH, from BrE perspective I think "switchback" is likely to be better understood than "serpentine". Although both are non-BrE. Just my opinion.

Comment: Although I knew what the asker meant describing the road as 'serpentine', that's not a word I believe I've ever heard applied to a road, and only understood it in the general sense of being snaky and curvy. If we're talking about a road that goes back and forth to help with extreme elevation changes, then that is a switchback.

Answer (score 3):

In england we do not speak of  serpentine roads and a swichback  (n) is not a road and a switchback (adj) road is not a bendy one.  We are notorious for winding roads but these are not necessarily winding to ascend a hill or mountain.   Meandering is more often applied to a river than a road and would not describe a bendy climbing road.   We speak of hairpin BENDS rather than curves or corners. I do not think there is in British English a particular noun or adjective pertaining particularly to roads made with bends to reduce the gradient on a hill.  This may be due to lack of mountains and hence such roads in england; there may be Welsh or Scottish words for such.

Comment: Your fellow countryman @David Richerby says that you guys "definitely can" use 'serpentine' to describe such a road. Apparently you are saying that even though you can, that nevertheless you actually do not? I have to agree about the lack of any actual mountains in England (been there, done missed them).  At any rate, it is no surprise that you use different words ('bends' instead of 'curves'); that is often the case.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a 'road' you could instead call it a 'track.'  'Track' refers to it being a dirt, rather than sealed, road.  So 'winding track' rather than 'winding road,' for example.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/track

Comment: The road op linked is not made of dirt... and its rather sealed :)

Answer (score 0):

This would be a road containing many s-bends or hair-pin corners.

Comment: Hi Tom. The question is looking for single word or phrase, so I don't think this really answers the question better than the existing answers.

Comment: @Colleen - I don't think a new answer needs to answer a question _better than_ existing answers. If it adds something useful, it's worth adding. This answer may be scant on details but I think those are worthy ways of describing such a roadway.

Comment: @Tom Bandy Could you add a geographic region where your terms are used? (Where you are from)

Comment: @J.R. You're correct that the answer doesn't have to be "better than" - I was rushing and could have expressed myself better. My main concern is that the answer doesn't fit into the context of writing the article mentioned in the question - it might if it had more detail or some examples added to it. I'm not the source of the downvotes by the way, and I didn't vote to delete when it came up in the review queue because of its length. I think it's a useful answer, but it could be much better.

Answer (score 0):

The word that you are looking for is "***meandering***".

Comment: The way you've worded your answer, it almost sounds like _meandering_ is **the** right word – or at least superior to the others. I might agree it's a _possible_ word, but can't agree it's "THE word that" the O.P. is "looking for". I wonder if you said that just to reach the requisite number of characters, but, if so, it would have been better to list a definition, or quote a published usage pertaining to roads, or maybe indicate whether you suggest this as a verb, adjective, or noun, since it can used as be [all three](https://www.wordnik.com/words/meandering).

Comment: Meandering suggests (at least to me) that the route is haphazard, which is not true of roads that climb mountains.

Comment: @Poly - To be fair, the O.P.'s question did specify: _usually .. constructed in the mountain areas, but not only_

Comment: It is an option, but meandering applies directly to slow running rivers; if applied to a road, it implies it is a lazy kind of road, which might not invoke the right image.

Comment: "I’m looking for a word or a phrase for describing this kind of road"
This is the question I responded to. While I would have loved to extend my answer to include more worded padding, I prefer getting to the point (just my preference) - @J.R.
Meandering is used to define roads that are not direct, meaning for example roads in the mountains that have to wind and curve to compensate for the large slopes that exist in those areas

Answer (score 0):

It is called a **mountain pass**.

You can definitely use words like "serpentine", "sinuous", "winding" and so on to describe such a road but they're just appropriate adjectives. To give an analogy, answering the question "What is this type of road called?" with "a serpentine road" is a bit like answering "What is this this type of animal called?" with "a huge animal" rather than "an elephant".

Comment: In American English, a *mountain pass* is road that passes through two mountains. Indeed, this is the historical meaning of mountain pass. It can be more straight than curved. As for *roads* along a mountain pass, see for example, [mountain passes](http://www.colorado.com/articles/spring-drives-colorado-mountain-passes) in Colorado.

Comment: Note a mountain pass will be serpentine and be composed of many switchbacks and, if one likes, hairpin turns, as it ascends or descends a mountain. Once at a certain elevation, a mountain pass (i.e, the road) can be straight for quite awhile.

Answer (score -2):

Snaking road.
To me, the Serpentine is a lake in Hyde Park, London, it isn't really bendy either.

Comment: That's just a particular use of "Serpentine", which is irrelevant to the question. It's like objecting to the use of the word "street" to talk about a road on the grounds that Street is a [town in Somerset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street,_Somerset).

Comment: My answer was snaking. It was too short on its own, so i added my observation about serpentine, which to people in London is probably relevant. I've never heard of anything described as serpintine before reading the earlier answers. Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: Your sarcastic criticism is unwarranted. Also, bear in mind that, while you can correlate votes and comments to your heart's content, you do not know who voted. The minimum answer length is there for a reason and, if you find yourself bumping into it, that's a really big hit that you're writing a bad answer.

Comment: TBH, the lake in Hyde Park (London) is the first thing I thought of too (and I'm not from London, although I am a Brit)! And I too (being a Brit) have never heard the term "serpentine" to describe "winding" or "snaking" roads. (+1)